# Get application context from a secondary module

Tags: android, android-context

I am working on a project that has one main module(here I have the activities and the controllers..) and some secondary modules where I have some calendar and other implementations.

In the main module I have a Application singleton class where I store the application context and I can get the app context statically from everywhere within my main module.

The question is how can I make another application class in the secondary module?  Currently I am using circular dependencies between the main module and the module where I want the app context, and I don't like too much to use this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David Wasser wrote:

> Why can't the code in the secondary modules call MainApp.getInstance() to get the application context? Obviously the secondary module is dependent on the main module so I don't see how this is a circular dependency.
>
> If not, then pass the singleton application context from the main module to the secondary modules (either as a parameter in method calls or as a parameter in the constructor of the component in the secondary module. Then you won't have code in the secondary modules calling `MainApp.getInstance()`. In any case you cannot have **another application class** as there is only one application class.

Comment: ([Question answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))